# How to merge elements in array by first words in JS? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array

```
['.some_class &.green_mod','.some_class &.red_mod','another_class &.green_mod','another_class &.orange_mod']
```

I want to get this array from it:

```
['.some_class &.green_mod &.red_mod','another_class &.green_mod &.orange_mod']
```

Is it possible?

Comment: if structure of input is defined as above, then its quite possible

Comment: It's possible, yes; but what's the logic? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I write a function, that get all elements on the page and put code with css selectors to my scss file)It is mods of classes with '&' sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
var preArr = ['.some_class &.green_mod', '.some_class &.red_mod', 'another_class &.green_mod', 'another_class &.orange_mod'];
var newArr = [];
preArr.forEach(function (item) {
    var has = false;
    var preWords = item.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; ++i) {
        var newWords = newArr[i].split('&');
        if (newWords[0] == preWords[0]) {
            has = true;
            for (var j = 0; j < preWords.length; ++j) {
                if (newWords.indexOf(preWords[j]) < 0) {
                    newWords.push(preWords[j]);
                }
            }
            newArr[i] = newWords.join('&');
        }
    }
    if (!has) {
        newArr.push(item);
    }
});
console.log(newArr);
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/lebubajesa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = (function() {
  var fmap1 = function(e) { return e.trim().split(/\s+/); };
  var fmap2 = function(e) { return e.join(" "); };
  var fsort = function(e1,e2) { return e1[0] == e2[0] ? 0 : e1[0] > e2[0] ? 1 : -1; };
  return function test(a) {
    var a1 = a.map(fmap1).sort(fsort);
    var s, a2 = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = a1.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (s != a1[i][0]) {
        s = a1[i][0];
        a2.push([s]);
      }
      a1.push.apply(a2[a2.length - 1], a1[i].slice(1));
    }
    return a2.map(fmap2);
  };
})();

var arr = ['  .some_class &.green_mod',' another_class &.green_mod','.some_class &.red_mod','another_class &.orange_mod'];
console.log(test(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
var arr = ['.some_class &.green_mod','.some_class &.red_mod','another_class &.green_mod','another_class &.orange_mod'];
var obj = {};
var finalArr = [];
for(var i=0,c=arr.length;i<c;i++)
{
    var parts = arr[i].split(' ');
    var key = parts[0];
    if(!obj[key]) obj[key] = [];
    obj[key].push(parts.slice(1).join(' '));
}
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for(var i=0,c=keys.length;i<c;i++)
{
    var key = keys[i];
    finalArr.push(key+' '+obj[key].join(' '))
}
console.log(finalArr);
```

Basically just loop through each one, and use the first word as a key to an array of strings to be appended, then loop through the object and join the keys with all of their array elements.

N.B. References  to `key` are the first word

Answer (score 0):

Solution bellow for data like key+separator+value where you are sure that there is no duplication in keys or You do not care if values are duplicated

```
// maping function that treats part before separator as key and saves incremetaly 
// all values under that key (duplicated vales are possible)
// only one separator per input entry is allowed
function mapFun (el, obj, separator) {
    var e = el.split(separator);
    var key = e[0];
    var val = e[1];
    obj[key] = obj[key] ? obj[key] + separator + val : separator + val; 
}

function combineClasses (arr) {
    var result = [];
    var separator = ' &';
    var obj = Object.create(null);  // create empty object without any properties or inheritance chain

    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        mapFun(arr[i], obj, separator);
    }

    for (var p in obj) {
        result.push (p + obj[p]);
    }

    return result;
}
combineClasses(arr);
```

Bellow solution will work for data like before and data like key+separator+value1+separator+value2 and will not allow for duplicated values for the same key

```
function mapFun (el, separator, obj) {
    var parts = el.split(separator);
    var key = parts[0];
    if (!obj[key]) {
        obj[key] = Object.create(null);     
    }
    for (var i=1; i<parts.length; i++) {
        obj[key][parts[i]] = null;  
    }
}

function combineClasses (arr) {
    var result = [];
    var separator = ' &';
    var obj = Object.create(null);            // create empty object without any properties     

    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        mapFun(arr[i], separator, obj);
    }

    for (var p in obj) {
        var values = Object.keys(obj[p]).join(separator);
        result.push (p + separator + values);
    }
    return result;
}

combineClasses(arr);
```

arr is where Your data comes in

```
var arr = ['.some_class &.green_mod','.some_class &.red_mod','another_class &.green_mod','another_class &.orange_mod']
```